# Trying to use simple_form radio button to input value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am trying to use simple_form radio button collection to categorize my post, however, it seems the value cannot be read by model.

The following are codes

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 create_table :posts do |t|
  t.text :content
  t.integer :category
  t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.references :comment

  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
end
```

And while I made the post like the following

```
<%= simple_form_for:post do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category, [[1,"Joke "],[2,"Gossip "],[3,"option3 "],[4,"option4 "]], :first, :last %>
   <%= f.text_area :content  %>
   <%= f.button :submit, "Post" %>          
<% end %>
```

No matter what I click on the radio button. the results are the same

```
Post Load (12.7ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Post id: 17, content: "test again",  category: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-12-13 05:47:09", updated_at: "2017-12-13 05:47:09">
```

**category: nil**

How to input the value by click a radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `]`,  change line

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category, [[1,"Joke "],[2,"Gossip "],[3,"option3 "],[4,"option4 "], :first, :last %>
```

with

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category, [[1,"Joke "],[2,"Gossip "],[3,"option3 "],[4,"option4 "]], :first, :last %>
```

Comment: My code on computer is correct. Just miss type a " ] " on stackoverflow when ask this question. The problem is still exist.

Comment: can you paste controller code as well. Have you permit category in controller?/

Answer (score 0):

your `category` column is integer type so i think secound argument of array should be integer instead of string, lets try this.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category, [["Joke ",1],["Gossip ",2],["option3 ",3],["option4 ",4]], :first, :last %>
```